# Reduce MOV file size

Tags: video-conversion, quicktime

I have a folder full of MOV videos taken by my [DMC-FX10](http://www.dpreview.com/news/2007/1/31/panasonicfx10fx12). The problem is that the occupy too much space, and I am wondering if it is possible to compress them **without losing quality**?

All videos have a resolution of **640*480**.

Example: `3 minutes` video @ `30 fps` takes **`240 Mb`** of space with a `data rate` of `11446 kbps` and a similar total bitrate.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I imagine ffmpeg could reduce the size of those videos:

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mov -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -crf 20 newmovie.mov
```

Or just download Handbrake if you want something with a GUI. Handbrake will also allow you to queue re-encodes.

Comment: Beware that you will lose quality no matter what. The movies from the camera are already compressed with a lossy codec, so there's not much you can squeeze out there without losing quality.